# Force compilation fail to indicate that developer attention required

Tags: java, code-generation

I'm making a code generation library.

On some edge cases the library can't generate the code and developer attention is needed. I want to mark places like this with something that will cause compile errors, so developer can go through all these places in a convenient way and fix all the problems.

What will be the best way to produce compile errors like that?

Comment: How do you expect your library to be called? I would say that providing error output in response to code generation call is the expected behavior.

Comment: Use the [XText](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) framework to create a DSL, including validations and and custom errors.

Comment: @AlehMaksimovich via command line. It generates pojos from json and I want to mark places in the generated code where type of a field is impossible to determine. I think marking these places in the code will be a better UX just failing right away.

Comment: Take java compiler for instance - it provides you with the text output with reference to code pieces affected. Later some tool can be used to map these exceptions to code (e.g. IDE plugin). It feels that you want to replace custom plug-in with compiler but it doesn't feel right.